# Facebook API class doesn't exist anymore

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook

I am trying to follow this guide to use Facebook on my site:

http://www.deviantcoders.com/articles/aspnet-membership-and-role-provider-facebook-connect-part-2

But when I try to use `API api = new API();` it can't find the class:

```
The type or namespace name 'API' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What assembly am I missing, I have added:

```
Facebook.Web
Facebook.Web.Mvc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, I found out that the framwork has changed. Now you need to initilize it this way:

```
public ConnectSession _connectSession _connectSession = new ConnectSession(APPLICATION_KEY, SECRET_KEY);
public Api _facebookAPI = new Api(_connectSession);
```

Source: http://facebook.claritycon.com/help/ -> Asp.net Development -> Connect

Answer (score 0):

The api has changed. Now facebook provides graph api. So the class api does not exist.