# Login using Facebook, missing namespace?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I am trying to integrate a login with facebook feature in my website and following [this article](http://devtacular.com/articles/bkonrad/how-to-retrieve-user-data-from-facebook-connect-in-aspnet).

This line gives me a "Missing directive or assembly reference error. The type or namespace could not be found."  I have placed the binaries as well.

```
API api = new API();
```

Which namespace contains the `API` class or is it no longer supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Facebook API class doesn't exist anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065199/facebook-api-class-doesnt-exist-anymore)

Comment: The OP apparently realizes this is an issue with using statements, since the question is about *what to include*...

Comment: private Api _facebookAPI;
This again gives the error.
The problem is with namespace
Do you have a working solution?

Comment: Not really, sorry... what namespaces are you including in your code?

Comment: I have solved the issue but stucked in another problem.
I have referenced Facebook.dll and Facebook.Web.dll earlier but still i needed to reference the api as Facebook.Rest.Api and it worked well.

Now another problem creeps up -> if someone is logged into my site and he logs out of facebook.com site and tries to login using facebook from my site then ERROR. It says session error because the user has logged out.

Comment: I have shared the code here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178945/login-using-facebook-problem-after-logging-out

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> while your caret is within `API` to see what namespaces contain the `API` class.

Comment: There isn't any.
On doing the same it says generate class for API?

Comment: @Jayesh: Oh well.  You wouldn't want to generate a class for API since it would just be an empty class.