# Login using Facebook Problem after logging out

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using facebook sdk and facebook connect for integrating fb into my site using asp.net and c#. The user can login using the code successfully. The problem that I face is that whenever a user is logged in thru fb; if the user logs out from the facebook's site and then tries to login through my site using fb connect, it gives error: The session is invalid because the user logged out.

I should again provide the facebook connect button to log in as it does initially but it gives error. The code used is shown below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (ConnectAuthentication.isConnected())
            {
                Facebook.Session.ConnectSession _connectSession = new Facebook.Session.ConnectSession(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiKey"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppSecret"]);
                if (!_connectSession.IsConnected())
                {
                    lblStatus.Text = "Please sign-in with Facebook.";
                }
                else
                {
                    Facebook.Rest.Api api = new Facebook.Rest.Api(_connectSession);

                    Facebook.Schema.user user = api.Users.GetInfo();
                    string fullName = user.first_name + " " + user.last_name;
                    lblStatus.Text = fullName;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lblStatus.Text = "Please sign-in with Facebook.";
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user logs out the session is invalidated. You need to have the user log in again. If you don't want to do that then please request the "offline_access" extended permission during authentication. This way the user does not have to be logged-in.

FYI, you will have to move to OAuth before September 1st 2011. Facebook will ONLY support OAuth after that.

Comment: Won't facebook development kit and facebook connect be supported?
Will i have to change the above code again then?

Comment: Only OAuth will be supported. The old REST token will not be supported any longer. So yes, you will have to migrate to OAuth.
I am also in the same boat and in the process of migrating to OAuth. The old Facebook Development Toolkit is obsolete now. Check the Facebook Developer roadmap url http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/

Comment: Damn!!!
Thanks for informing. Can you share me the safe link which would be the best to follow?

Comment: It is actually simpler than the old method. You can get all info here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: Try this link: http://osnapz.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/using-asp-net-with-facebooks-graph-api-and-oauth-2-0-authentication/  You don't really need to use the Facebook C# SDK for this. It is pretty straight-forward.

Comment: Hi,
Connecting through the new method was easier :)
Can you say me how to store username or name in any variable in c#?
I tried this but got 400 bad request error:
string url_username = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token" + oAuth.Token;
var usrnm = oAuth.WebRequest(oAuthFacebook.Method.GET, url_username,"username")

Comment: To make Graph API calls you can use the Facebook C# SDK. Once you have the access token, you should save it some where (database, preferably). You can download the SDK here: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20Examples&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: If you want to make a straight WebRequest, then you need to call this URL: "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=<YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN>&fields=username" . You will have to parse the result JSON string.

Comment: SDK is better :)
New method is easier than earlier :)