# Facebook C# SDK: OAuth 2 in Silverlight 4 browser app

Tags: silverlight-4.0, oauth, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm completely newbie at authentication proccess with OAuth (I'm trying to make use of OAuth 2, exactly), and the example I am following to authenticate by using Facebook SDK latest release says that this code snippet should work for C# .NET environments (http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-first-Facebook-Application.aspx):

```
webBrowser.Navigate(loginUrl);

private void webBrowser_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    FacebookOAuthResult result;
    if (FacebookOAuthResult.TryParse(e.Url, out result))
    {
       if (result.IsSuccess)         
       {
         var accesstoken = result.AccessToken;          
       }

       else
       {
         var errorDescription = result.ErrorDescription;
         var errorReason = result.ErrorReason;
       }
    }
}
```

Since I am programming a browser SL app, the WebBrowser control displays nothing, so I am not either able to catch the response, how could I do something equivalent to that in my app? Or how could I manage to complete the authentication proccess if there is no equivalent way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A suggestion: Why don't you try to parse the WebResponse when you receive it as opposed to listening for the event?

I use Facebook OAuth in my web app. It is nothing but a series of URL posts with the correct parameters.

Take a look at this post: [Login using Facebook Problem after logging out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178945/login-using-facebook-problem-after-logging-out) (All the details are in the answer and comments)

Here are the brief steps:

1. Call the Facebook OAuth Dialog URL with your AppId, redirect url, and permissions. Request_type should be "code"
2. When the user logs in and authorizes you application, they will be redirected to the redirect url with a "code" querystring parameter.
3. Take the value of the code parameter and make another call to Facebook to get the token.
4. Use this token to make calls on the user's behalf.

Comment: I managed to complete the authentication process following those steps, but setting request_type as "token", thanks!

Comment: The only reason I stressed on "code" was for security reasons. The "token" request type is embedded in the query string, therefore, not secure. It is easily intercept-able. With "code", you have to make another POST call to get the token and this is more secure. You can also use the "state" parameter for more security.

Comment: I'll try if it also works for me stating the request_type as "code" as you have suggested, thank you

Comment: I'm now taking a look at that, but I'm not sure about that security issue (maybe I haven't really understood the process), I mean, I set the response type and the rest of the parameters in my Silverlight client, where I also make the first request to the Facebook API, but the callback url I set is an aspx page in server-side, where I get the url by means of a JavaScript function to return it to the Silverlight client.

Comment: Since even if I set the request_type as "code", I'll catch the response in my aspx page to later pass it to the silverlight client-side page by means of a call to the JavaScript function, the same way I directly did when I set it to "token", how does using "code" take advantage of a better security? Though you make one more POST call, the final response goes to the same callback url and in the same format, doesn´t it? So is it not as interceptable as if "token" request_type stated?

Comment: In request type "token", the token is embedded in the URL. With "code", you have to make another HTTP POST call to get the access token. This token is returned as part of the HTTP response.

Comment: Looks like calling for the access token by POST method is not working anymore, my app stopped working and now I switched to GET method it is working again